# How to go mod get local package?

Tags: go, go-modules

I want go.mod get a folder inside the selfCheck(get package inside selfCheck folder).

`selfCheck/encrypt , selfCheck/searchSchool`

my screenshots is here

[image]

(don't mind vendor file. i'll remove it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to require a folder in the project itself in go.mod files. `go.mod` is only requireing external packages from other repositories.

I wrote a blogpost on starting with Go that covers this question. https://marcofranssen.nl/start-on-your-first-golang-project

I also wrote a whole bunch more articles on Go https://marcofranssen.nl/categories/golang

In summary what you should do it use the full url of your git repository so other projects can depend on it as a best practice.

e.g.

`go mod init github.com/your-user/selfcheck`

Once you did that your `go.mod` file looks like this.

```
module github.com/your-user/selfcheck

go 1.17
```

Please note camel casing is not the way you name go packages. Go packages should be all lowercase.

Now if you want to create sub packages as you are asking for you should create folders. e.g. your project could look like this.

```sh
$ tree selfcheck
selfcheck
├── go.mod
├── main.go
└── searchschool
    └── searchschool.go

1 directory, 3 files
```

Now to reference code from the `searchschool` package you can do the following in `main.go`.

```golang
package main

require (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/your-user/selfcheck/searchschool"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(searchschool.Excute())
}
```

Please note all functions have to start with an uppercase to access them outside of the searchschool package. E.g. `searchschool/searchschool.go`

```golang
package searchschool

func Execute() string {
    return privateFunc() + "!"
}

func privateFunc() string {
    return "Hello World"
}
```